# Using Max on a Table joined with another

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

The goal is to create an overview of data records. These records come from multiple tables. One of these Tables holds several rows per record, each having an ID number. Only the one with the highest ID number should be shown.

I've tried doing some things with Inner Joins but i can't get it right.

a simplified view of the problem:

```
Tabel1      
Tabel1_Id   ValueA      ValueB
1           ABC         DEF
2           GHI         JKL
3           MNO         PQR
4           STU         VWX
```

---

```
Tabel2          
Tabel2_id   Tabel1_Id   Number      ValueC
1           1           1           Green
2           1           2           Yellow
3           2           1           Blue
4           1           3           Red
5           3           1           Purple
6           3           2           Pink
7           2           2           Violet
8           4           1           Magenta
9           2           3           Cyan
10          4           2           Teal
```

---

```
Desired Result      
ValueA  ValueB  ValueC
ABC     DEF     Red
GHI     JKL     Cyan
MNO     PQR     Pink
STU     VWX     Teal
```

Comment: @jarlh MYSQL is the one

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @jarlh  Honestly don't know.

Comment: Try Zaynul's query below. It will perhaps run on newer MySQL versions.

Comment: I have added tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group] You should get 100s of similar problem as your question. Also, the duplicate marked questions have answers for all the different versions of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

if your DBMS support `row_number()` then you can use below

```
with cte as
(select *,row_number()over(partition by Tabel1_Id order by Number desc) rn
from table2
) select valueA,valueV,valuec
 from cte join table1 t1 on cte.Tabel1_Id=t1.Tabel1_Id
  where cte.rn=1
```